# Calling Heroku Postgres Stored Procedure from APEX class

Tags: apex, api, postgres

I'm attempting at using Heroku as an External data source for my Salesforce ORG and run process heavy transformation tasks.

I have created my Postgres DB on Heroku, Installed the Salesforce connector and have no problems mapping tables and using tables on Postgres as External data sources.

However, what I'm trying to do now is call a Stored Procedure in Postgres from an APEX class to update changes to the data. I've searched everywhere far and wide but can't seem to find anything.
I know you can achieve this using Mulesoft but I'm trying to avoid middleware tools.

Comment: If by _Salesforce connector_ you mean [Heroku Connect](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect), then no, you can't call a stored proc. Heroku Connect auto-updates, so your question sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).